# SQL query how to simplify several 'case when' (more than 26 Summarizing items)

Tags: python, sql

Supposed I have some sample data in `table_x` as below:

```
    code_x   code_y      val            date
   -------------------------------------------
1   00001    111         500         20191107
2   00001    222         1000        20191107
3   00002    333         200         20191108
4   00002    444         400         20191108
.....
99  00029    888         200         20191111
100 00030    999         400         20191112
```

And some sample data in `table_y` as below:

```
 table_x.code_y   remark
-------------------------
1   111            a
2   222            b
3   333            c
4   444            d 
5   555            b 
6   666            e 
 ....
100 999            z
```

When I input code '00001' and the date between '20191101' and '20191112', I need the output as below: （Summarize the value of remark from 'a' to 'z', total 26 items）

```
        code   value_of_remark_a  value_of_remark_b  ....... value_of_remark_z 
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   00001        500             1000            .......   2000
```

Below output is also fine for us:

```
        code     val     remark
        ---------------
    1  00001     500       a 
    2  00001     1000      b 
     ........
    26 00001     500       z
```

This SQL query as below, is there any easy SQL query? Do I have to write 26 times `case when remark = a` to `case when remarking =z`?

```
SELECT t.code_x,
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark='a' then t.val ELSE 0 END ) AS val_of_a,
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark='b' then t.val ELSE 0 END ) AS val_of_b,
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark='c' then t.val ELSE 0 END ) AS val_of_c,
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark='d' then t.val ELSE 0 END ) AS val_of_d,
    -- The remark from 'a' to 'z', totle 26 items
    -- Is there any easy query to instead of these redundant SQL query?
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark='z' then t.val ELSE 0 END ) AS val_of_z
FROM table_x t
LEFT JOIN table_y t1
    ON t.code_y = t1.code_y
WHERE t.code_x IN ('%(code_x)s')
    AND t.code_x BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
GROUP BY t.code_x, t.date
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: what's the `sql version`?

Comment: Your code is fine.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I am sorry, why does it matter?

Comment: `'%(code_x)s' %(start_date)s %(end_date)s`  i don't think t-sql understand these codes unless if this is something new that i am not aware of

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Hi，please ignore those code, those are python code

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I have to verify it when our company's server is ready......

```
SELECT t.code_x, val, t1.remark
FROM(
    SELECT t.code_x,
    sum(CASE WHEN t1.remark IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'......'z') then t.value ELSE 0 END ) AS val,
    FROM tabl_x t
    LEFT JOIN table_y t1
        ON t.code_y = t1.code_y
    WHERE t.code_x IN ('%(code_x)s')
        AND t.code_x BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
    GROUP BY t.code_x, t.date) AS res
```